# Function::Parameters - what does "In method ...: missing type name after '['"

Tags: perl

I have a problem using module `Function::Parameters` with `Types::Standard`. In this code, in Person.pm:

```
package Person;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Function::Parameters;
use Types::Standard qw(InstanceOf);

method is_taller_than(
  InstanceOf['Person'] $other
) {
  return;
}

1;
```

Using `perl -cw Person.pm` reports:

```
In method is_taller_than: missing type name after '[' at Person.pm line 9.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I created this question and answered it since: a) I read somewhere that was a valid thing to do, especially since; b) I was stumped by this question and spent much time Googling before stumbling over the answer.

If people are finding the answer useful, is the question not also useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a parsing limitation in `Function::Parameters`. It can handle barewords and square brackets, but not quoted strings. The way to get around this is just to put parentheses around the type expression:

```
method is_taller_than(
  (InstanceOf['Person']) $other
) {
```

Comment: Another workaround: `use constant { InstanceOfPerson => InstanceOf['Person'] }; method is_taller_than(InstanceOfPerson $other) { ... }`. Or even `use constant { Person => 'Person' }; method is_taller_than(InstanceOf[Person] $other) { ... }`.

Comment: Good pointers! Why not make them full "answers" to the question? I have no problem accepting someone else's answer instead of mine (in a few days) if it looks like the best one!